# MyISAM for logging and export?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

in "High Performance MySQL" from o'Reilly I've read, that MyISAM could be a good alternative to InnoDB for logging situations.
So we've a high rate of INSERTs on some tables, so MyISAM can be used, but there is also an export of old data every 3 minutes (so the table is dumped and flushed every 3 minutes and the data is transferred to another server). Has anyone experience in such a situation? Could MyISAM really be a good choice to InnoDB (which we are currently using)?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use replication, dump on slave, and flush the master daily.